# Trying to make a basic instantiation example but unable

Tags: java, arrays, instantiation, instance-variables

So I have only recently started coding Java through learning platforms like Lynda.com, hackerranks, SoloLearn and codeacademy.com

I recently started learning about instance variables, instance methods and instantiation. Following the good old "do it to learn it" mentality I wrote a small script that essentially builds and returns a 4x4 2D int array into an instance variable and then prints the instance variable array using an instance method. Hopefully im not confusing myself with all these terms. Here is my code:

```
package com.company;

public class Main {

    // created an instance variable called "fill" which is a 2D array
    public int[][] fill;

    // Created an instance method called "displayArray()" to print the array matrix upon call
    private void displayArray() {

        for ( int i = 0; i < fill.length; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < fill[i].length; j++){
                System.out.print(this.fill[i][j] + " " );
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    // Main method to assign values to the 2D instance variable "fill"

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Main array = new Main(); // instantiation to allow use of "displayArray()" and to allow instance variable "fill" to be filled with integer values
        array.fill = new int[4][4]; // Initiating instance variable "fill"

        //Filling in the 2D array which is an instance variable "fill"
        for (int i = 0; i < array.fill.length; i++){

            for (int j = 0; j < array.fill.length; j++){
                if ( i == j) {
                    array[i][j] = array.fill.length;
                } else {
                    array[i][j] = array.fill.length - Math.abs(i-j);
                }
            }
        }

        // Calling an instance method "displayArray()" to print out array values to console
        array.displayArray();
        }
}
```

However, I keep getting the errors:

```
Error:(40, 26) java: array required, but com.company.Main found
Error:(44, 26) java: array required, but com.company.Main found
```

I am kind of lost as to how to fix it. Am I overlooking something? or can I not create instance variables/methods in a Main class?

Answer (score 1):

You are using confusing names, so you have just forgotten to append the variable `fill`(that is actually the array) after the object `array`(that is the actual object name for your class Main):

Try this:

```java
if (i == j) {
   array.fill[i][j] = array.fill.length;
} else {       
   array.fill[i][j] = array.fill.length - Math.abs(i - j);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful!!

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `Main array = new Main();` will create an object called array, which is an instance of the class `Main`.

Then you are initialising the array `fill` using the line `array.fill = new int[4][4];`.

As you can see these names are confusing. Better to use non-confusing names. For an example use

```
public int[][] array;
```

instead of

```
public int[][] fill;
```

Then you can instantiate them as follows:

```
Main main_object = new Main();
main_object.array = new int[4][4];
```

Now you can use your loop to fill the array with corresponding values.

Make sure to use proper names for your classes and variables in the future. Otherwise it will hard to understand your code and to find errors.

Comment: Ahhh ok I see, thank you!!

My apologies, still getting used to the common developer naming habits to make my code easier to read!